# Shortcut for go to previous line visited?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there any shortcut for `Go to Previous line visited` in the editor .

Thank you ,

Kannan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Q goes to your Last Edit Location (at least in OS X).

See the "Navigate" menu.